# How to write analyzed data from wso2 DAS to custom database for API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

In my case i'm using wso2 api manager and Data analytic server. I need to show the analyzed data on the api manager publisher or subscriber accounts which are analyzed by the DAS. I rifer [reference source](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS)

In the DAS side I can see the results perfectly. But can't see the statistics from the API manager side. 
Only I can see "Data Publishing Enabled, Generate some traffic" message.
Not getting any error too.
please guide me how can I resolve this.

[Edited]I got this exception after following the steps mentioned in the @Prabudda Sri Rahal 's answer. [image]

So how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Which API Manager version you are using and where did you check the statistics?

Comment: I just install the same applications, and I had some troubles after configuring everything (using REST connection to DAS). Maybe restart both application and check ports.

Comment: I used the latest version.1.10.0

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque what kind of configurations you did in the DAS side? (specially in the event streams, event receivers and event publishers)

Comment: I use the compiled DAS for API Manager, I think it's already configured for API Manager. So I do nothing in DAS but configure in API Manager adresses.

Comment: no i had to write event publishers to store the event streams to the database tables. Then api manager could read and represent these statistical data on apim side also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add API_Manager_Analytics.car file to DAS as a carbon application. Then it creates all the necessary streams, event receivers. But it doesn't create event publishers to publish these data to our custom database. For that need to create event publishers manually to write on the database tables by mapping correct stream attributes with the database column names.
Refered:  [enter link description here](http://www.rukspot.com/Publishing_APIM_Runtime_Statistics_to_DAS.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the API_Manager_Analytics.car as described in
[this](http://www.rukspot.com/Publishing_APIM_Runtime_Statistics_to_DAS.html) blog.

Comment: I tried with this. But got some exception as follows

Comment: Just execute the scripts in Home  > Manage  > Batch Analytics  > Scripts manually. Or reduce the time in Cron Expression. By default it runs every 5min.